# Showing all the table rows on the last page with pagination on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show the last page of pagination instead of the first page on load.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data').after('<div id="nav"></div>');
    var rowsShown = 5;
    var rowsTotal = $('#data tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
    for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a> ');
    }
    $('#data tbody tr').hide();
    $('#data tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
    $('#nav a').bind('click', function(){

        $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
        var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
        var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
        $('#data tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
        css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="data" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently, each row has 1 data, there are 2 data for example purposes. Which means there are 2 pages in the pagination which is 1 and 2, When the page load, I need it to load page 2 which is the last page instead of the first page.

When the row is added, there may be 10 pages, and when the page load, i need it to load the last page which is page 10.

Comment: Code Snippet is not working. Try with codepen

Comment: If you don't put `<script>` tags in the JS part, it'll work.

Comment: Like `$('#nav a').last().click()`?

Comment: Something like that, instead of clicking manually to the last page, the page will show the table from the last page on page load. For example, the active page will be active on the last page when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) method on a jQuery selector to select the last element in a query and set it's state.

**Edit:** The way you should toggle through multiple rows, is exactly the same. Do it by splitting your tables into smaller chunks and toggle the visibility of the tables.

I've update my answer below and upgraded your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data').after('<div id="nav"></div>');
    
    // Select all the tables.
    var $tables = $('#data table');
    
    var tablesShown = 1;
    var tablesTotal = $tables.length;
    var numPages = tablesTotal / tablesShown;
    for(var i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a> ');
    }
    
    // Select all links.
    var $navs = $('#nav a');
    
    // Hide all rows and show the last one.
    $tables.hide().last().show();
    
    // Add active to last link
    $navs.last().addClass('active');
    
    // Listen to click.
    // Use on instead of bind
    $navs.on('click', function(){
      $navs.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
      var $currentTable = $($tables.get(currPage));
      $tables.hide();
      $currentTable.show();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="data">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! This actually solve the problem! Thanks.

Comment: Hello, is there a way to show the last page instead of the last row in the last page? Lets say the last page has 5 rows, i need it to show all 5 rows of the last page, instead of the the last page, last row.

Comment: Can we assume that every page is represented by a `<table>` with 5 rows?

Comment: Yes, currently, I have edited the question to 10 rows, lets say 1 page has 5 rows, when the page load it should show those 5 rows on the last page, instead of the last row of the last page.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following line to your code:

```
$('#data tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
// addidional line
$('#data tbody tr').last().show();
```

this should show the last page.